Implementing Scroll with Sticky First Column and Row `ngx-datatable`
When the number of rows or columns increases, the content is not fully visible. How to implement a scroll feature, ensuring that the first column and first row remain fixed (sticky) while scrolling?
<ngx-datatable id="table" #table class="" [rows]="tt">
    <ngx-datatable-column name="b" prop="ff" ></ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column *ngIf="q" name="Site No" prop="ff"></ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="q" prop="r" ></ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="ww" prop="ww" >
        <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row">
                                                  {{ row.qw| currency:'USD':'symbol':'1.2-2' }}
                                                </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>

I tried SCSS properties like z-index and wrap.

Mohsin please use the below code.
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false babelPresetReact: false babelPresetTS: false -->



      ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        // Check if the table size has changed,
        if (
          this.table &&
          this.table.recalculate &&
          this.tableWrapper.nativeElement.clientWidth !== this.currentComponentWidth
        ) {
          this.currentComponentWidth = this.tableWrapper.nativeElement.clientWidth;
          this.table.recalculate();
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }
      }
      @ViewChild(your own datatable reference ) tableWrapper;
      @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;

<!-- language: lang-css -->


    th:first-child,td:first-child{
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        overflow: scroll;
        }
    thead{
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        z-index: 9;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

